# How to pass parameters to an SLS file via another SLS file in SaltStack?

Tags: deployment, salt-stack

I have an SLS file in SaltStack Orchestrator which contains something like this:

```
Plan A:
  salt.state:
    - tgt: my-server
    - sls: service-a

Plan B:
  salt.state:
    - tgt: my-server
    - sls: service-a
    - onfail:
      - Plan A
```

And inside `service-a` SLS file I have something like this:

```
{% set image = pillar["image"] | default("service-api") %}
{% set version = pillar["version"] %}

Deploy A:
  cmd.run:
    - name: docker-compose -f {{version}}/docker-compose.yml up
    ..... (+ many lines of other commands and codes)
```

Now, the problem is, when `Plan A` failed, then `Plan B` should do the rollback, but it does the same and fails again because I didn't change the `version` variable inside the `service-a` SLS file. I want to change the `version` variable inside the `service-a` SLS file via the Orchestrator file. For example, when it goes to `Plan B` then it should change the `version` to `old`.
The only way I know is it can be handled by Python modules, but as far as possible I wanna address it by SLS files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the orchestrator file just add the `pillar` parameter:

```
Plan B:
  salt.state:
    - tgt: my-server
    - sls: service-a
    - pillar:
        version: old
    - onfail:
      - Plan A
```

**Only** in the state `Plan B`, the value of the `version` pillar will be `old`.